# is this the correct jsp/struts syntax?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am very new to this and I am trying to see if the domain name matches the one I specify. If the domain does not match production then I want to add noindex meta, it is a JSP page
Here is my code

```
<s:if test="%{!HttpServletRequest.getRequestUrl().containsIgnoreCase('www.example.com')}">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
</s:if>
```

I am very confused on what is the right syntax to use here, in the file I am editing there are things like
`<c:choose><c:when test="${!empty param.share_url}">`

and code like

```
<s:if test="%{sectionId == 'vehicles'}">
```

is my code correct for what I want to do?

Comment: That looks more like Struts to me, not JSTL

Comment: ok then it's struts I don't know what the exact correct name is

Comment: Don't just gloss over the distinction, the two are entirely separate.

Comment: I dunno which is which, I only know it is a jsp file and the file contains the syntax I listed above. I know the code I wrote did not work because I don't see the meta tag in my tests

Comment: `%{}` syntax is Struts2-specific OGNL. JSP uses `${}` syntax which is EL. JSTL is just another JSP taglib.

Comment: ok I don't understand server side coding that much I thought this would be something simple to do. is this not a one liner?

Comment: @Huangism: when you have question of Struts2 tag it with Struts2 tag else S2 community will not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with S2 than i suggest you to go ahead with S2 tag so that you can use the full power of S2 and its binding with the ONGL and Value-Stack.

If you want to use JSTL and you can use JSTL as S2 provides support for JSTL out of the box and until unless there is no utter need, do not mix ta library.

For the first part

```
<s:if test="%{!HttpServletRequest.getRequestUrl().containsIgnoreCase('www.example.com')}">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
</s:if>
```

You need not to play around with `HTTPServletRequest` while S2 provides a clean way to access request,session,application scope object.

Here is how we tend to access them in JSP

```
<s:property value="#request.myId" />
```

For more detail refer to the official documents

- [accessing-application-session-request-objects](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html)
- [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ognl.html)

Comment: apparently we had a variable setup as the domain already so I just compared that var to the prod string, but thanks for your input and effort

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done struts in a while as I defected to .net (sorry) but I seem to remember you can do it a couple of ways

1. `${request.requestURI}`
2. `<s:property value="%{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'].requestURI}"/>`

Apologies if this is now out of date.